# Difference between range and single value for df.loc first parameter in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

To select a single column in a pandas dataframe, should I use

`df.loc[3:3, :]`

or

`df.loc[3, :]`

They are not exactly equivalent as the first one displays a table in Jupyter whereas the second does not.

Comment: It depends on what you want the result to be. The first option returns a `DataFrame` containing the row at index `3`, the second returns row `3` as a `Series`. The first option is called `slicing range`, See the documentation for a list of options: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`df.loc[3:3, :]` means, prints the row with index 3 in Dataframe form.

`df.loc[3, :]` means, print the row with index 3 a in series form.

let's take an example of a ***DataFrame***:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1,5,10,12,15,18],'shift':['A','B','C','D','E','F']})
```

This is how DataFrame will look:

```
  shift  time
0     A     1
1     B     5
2     C    10
3     D    12
4     E    15
5     F    18
```

Now let us execute your statements one by one:

```
##1st code:
df.loc[3:3, :]

  shift time
3   D   12

 
##2nd code:
df.loc[3, :]

shift     D
time     12
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

Why because we are specifying a slicing range in first code `df.loc[3:3, :]` here though we are giving a range of `3:3` which will only print row with 3rd index. In second code `df.loc[3, :]` has no range so it will print it in a series form.